# Complete solution

Tags: reactjs, getstream-io

I use the [`<NotificationDropdown notify />`](https://getstream.github.io/react-activity-feed/#notificationdropdown) React component to get rendender a notification feed, but when I create `comment`, `like` or `post` reactions, the notification feed stays empty. Please help me solution this problem.

Comment: please add your component code

Answer (score 0):

Reactions by default don't get posted to any feed. They are only attached to the activity. If you want to post an activity to a feed when creating a reaction you need to use the [`targetFeeds`](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#reactions_notify-other-feeds).

So in your case you probably want to do something like:

```
client.reactions.add(
    "like", 
    activity.id, 
    {}, 
    {targetFeeds: ["notification:" + activity.actor.id]
)
```